# Holomorphic functions and functions which coincides

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I have a problem in which I have to find a non-constant function on $\mathbb{C} $ such that it has no zeros. That's clear, because the function $f(z)=e^z$, or more generally $f(z)=e^{g(z)}$ with $g(z)$ an entire number, has no zeros.

But the problem comes now. I am asked to find an holomorphic function also on $\mathbb{C}$ which coincides with $f$ on the disc $D(0,1)$, but is zero outside of $D(0,2)$.

**My guess:**

I think the function $h(z)=\sum \frac{z^n}{n!}$, which is the series expansion of the exponential function, coincides in the disc $D(0,1)$ with $f$ (Well, I'm not sure if I can use it, because, in fact, is the same function, doesn't it?)

But, I cannot find a function which matches the both criteria (coincides with $f$ in the unit disc, but it zero outside $D(0,2)$).

Comment: Only one holomorphic (analytic) function coincides with the zero function, that's the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).

Comment: this translates to 'mission impossible' :-)

Comment: @Dr.MV how does this admit a nonconstant extension to $\mathbb{C}$ without zeros?

Comment: It doesn't.  The only analytic extension of $0$ is $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say I have a function, holomorphic on $\Bbb{C}$ and $0$ outside the disk $D(0,2)$.  Then its modulus is a continuous function, particularly on the closed disk $\overline{D(0,3)}$.  This disk is compact, so the modulus attains a maximum, $M$, on that disk.  Then the function is bounded on $\Bbb{C}$ (by $\max\{M,0\}$).  By Liouville, it's constant.  We *know* it takes the value $0$, so the function is identically $0$.

Comment: So, as stated in the comments, it is impossible, isn't it?

Comment: @rdguez : Yes.  Impossible.